# Read all lines of csv file using .read_csv

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to read simple `csv` file using `pandas` but I can't figure out how to not "lose" the first row.

For example:

`my_file.csv`

Looks like this:

```
45
34
77
```

But when I try to to read it:

```
In [18]: import pandas as pd

In [19]: df = pd.read_csv('my_file.csv', header=False)

In [20]: df
Out[20]: 
   45
0  34
1  77

[2 rows x 1 columns]
```

This is not what I am after, I want to have 3 rows. I want my `DataFrame` to look exactly like this:

```
In [26]: my_list = [45,34,77]

In [27]: df = pd.DataFrame(my_list)

In [28]: df
Out[28]: 
    0
0  45
1  34
2  77

[3 rows x 1 columns]
```

How can I use `.read_csv` to get the result I am looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, this is a bit of a UI problem.  We should handle `False`; right now it thinks you want the header on row 0 (== False.) Use `None` instead:

```
>>> df = pd.read_csv("my_file.csv", header=False)
>>> df
   45
0  34
1  77
>>> df = pd.read_csv("my_file.csv", header=None)
>>> df
    0
0  45
1  34
2  77
```

Comment: Makes perfect sense! Thank You.

Comment: `False` is no longer an accepted argument for `header`